# Qt proxy model usage example

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am using a Qt 4's `QFileSystemModel` and `QTreeView`. I am writing a Windows Explorer like file manager, and want to make a tree more similar to  Windows', where tree consist some shortcut paths like Desktop, My Documents.
The only thing I want is to make a tree look like this:

- My Computer

  - Desktop
  - My Documents
  - C:\
  - D:\
  - ...

I heard that it can be achieved with `QAbstractProxyModel`.
Have any one used the `QAbstractProxyModel` and get it working? If yes please provide any appropriate example. Thanks in advance.

**This question is the same as [How to add custom row in QFileSystemModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885817/how-to-add-custom-row-in-qfilesystemmodel)**

Comment: I think you mixed up QGraphicsProxyWidget with QAbstractProxyModel

Comment: Now as you mentioned it, I remind that it should be `QIdentityProxyModel` or `QAbstractProxyModel`, or even both at the same time. Is there a way to change the title?

Comment: So essentially you want to have "aliases" in the tree, where one item virtually points to another item. I never did so and can't help you, but I think this should be possible with `QAbstractItemModel` I think the `QIdentityProxyModel` is the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more what is missing in QTreeView to handle your example tree?

What about using a simple QTreeView example like  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/QTreeViewdemoandQStandardItem.htm as a starting point to get what you are looking for?

Comment: In example you have provided they use `QStandardItemModel`, so you can add to standard model whatever you need. But `QFileSystemModel` takes its content from your file system, and by default it only contains _Drives_ (in Windows), so it looks like: C:\, D:\, .... The thing I need is - to add here two things: a shortcut to Desktop and My Documents. As I said before seems that this can be achieved using `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, but I can not get it working=(